# "Add driver" not on menu

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I'm trying to add a driver to a shape key but when I right click on the value line, the menu skips "Add Driver" and goes from "Insert Keyframe", "Clear Keyframe", to "Add to Keying Set".  I have Blender 2.74. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Bob :) If the answer solves your issue, please mark it as solved (checkmark below the reputation arrows). You could also start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to get your first badge. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you are already controlling the value with keyframes. Drivers and keyframes do not mix.

Select *Clear Keyframes* from the menu and then add driver.